# getStringArrayListExtra output with Square Brackets

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm learning Android Intent. I need to show a list of items when ShowList button is clicked, without using ListView or Spinner.Here are parts of my code:

FirstActivity Class (Main)

```
    // Add Item function
    public void AddItem (View v){
        if((TextUtils.isEmpty(item_in.getText().toString()))||(item_in.getText().toString().contains(" "))){
        input_error_alert.setMessage("Data was not correct").setPositiveButton("Edit data",null).show();
        }

        else{
        confirm_alert.setMessage("Data was correct").setPositiveButton("OK",null).show();
        ItemList.add(item_in.getText().toString());
        item_in.setText("");
        }
    }


    public void ShowList (View v){
    //Create intent to SecondActivity
     Intent show = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putStringArrayList("ItemList",ItemList);
     show.putExtras(b);
     startActivity(show);
}
```

SecondActivity Class

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    List = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.shopping_list);

    Intent show = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> Item_List = show.getStringArrayListExtra("ItemList");
    List.setText("Your shopping list includes: "+Item_List);

    }
```

The output I get is: "Your shoppping list includes: [item1, item2,...]. Could you help explain how those brackets [] appear in my output? How could I remove it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: :), because array is converting into readable(string) format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent show = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> Item_List = show.getStringArrayListExtra("ItemList");
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(100);

for(int i=0; i<= Item_list.size(); i++){
     s.append(list.get(i) + ",");
}
List.setText("Your shopping list includes: "+s.toString());
```